# Embedding image in and attaching files to email sent through Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, email, vba

I'm writing a piece of code to populate a spreadsheet, then email it out to a bunch of people with the spreadsheet as an attachment, along with an explanatory PDF and an HTML covering letter (featuring the company logo) in the email body.

Now, I've sent emails with Excel VBA code before, and I've formatted their layout with HTML in the `.HTMLBody`. But the other bits are causing me some bother.

The attachments I think I can figure out; I assume I can just use multiple `.Attachments.Add` with the various files, haven't tried that.

The main question is the company logo in the email body. I'm fairly well up on HTML, but I can't figure out how to actually embed a picture when I don't have a `src` for it.

Googling has produced a few approaches, but they've been `cid`-based and have had comments about only working if the reader uses Outlook.

Any suggestions? Is there a nice simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below code,

for attaching the image to your mail(add this under create mail object),

```
       .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\image.png"
```

add this into your mail body (assuming you are using table)

```
"<td Colspan=2><img src='cid:image.png' height=205 width=1015></td>"
```

Comment: Cheers - it works, but all of us here in the local office use Outlook, so I can't check if it works with other mail clients. Do you know if CID works in other clients?

Comment: This is created using simple HTML tags only so It should work